# Handling the triggering logic for in-app notifications on the app side?

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, react-native-marketingcloudsdk, in-app-guidance

When triggering in-app from marketing cloud how can we send metadata to the app if we want to handle the notification logic and message prompt dialog design on the app side? For example can we send keywords through marketing cloud and parse that on the app side and trigger accordingly? Is that done by parsing the URL for button actions?

Also, for in-home triggering logic we need to set the shouldShow to false and then add our own logic to trigger our internal modal, in other words we will return false for shouldShow for all events received and trigger our own logic from there. My question is that what happens to the event received from salesforce after we return false for shouldShow? Will it be discarded? Just want to make sure we are not missing anything here by returning false shouldShow for all salesforce events.